# How to lower freezing temperature of butterscotch?

Tags: sauce

My current butterscotch recipe is a simple brown sugar, butter, and cream. When attempting to use it as a topping for ice-cream, I have to heat it up to warm/hot to get it to be a liquid. After pouring it on some ice-cream, and in the time it takes to walk 20 feet from kitchen to living room, the butterscotch has already come back to cold and has become a sticky, solid texture.

What can I add to my butterscotch to lower its freezing/solidifying point so that it remains a viscous liquid when added to ice cream (like a consistency between maple syrup and molasses)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to achieve a thin caramel sauce/coating that stays fluid when refrigerated](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/16386/how-to-achieve-a-thin-caramel-sauce-coating-that-stays-fluid-when-refrigerated)

Comment: @Johanna possibly. There's a concern in that answer that adding an acid to a caramel recipe that uses cream may cause it to curdle...Given that butterscotch calls for cream by design, I'm not sure if this really helps. I can give it a test of course...but was hoping that someone may have already walked down this path?

Comment: I don't have the rep to bounty this question, but I came here to ask how to lower the freezing temperature of Ganashe, which has the very same problem, cream, and the top-voted answer to the Q referenced by @user141592 specifically wonders if the solution would work with cream. Well... time to experiment.